# Search Array In Python, Return Position

Tags: python, arrays

This Is Quite Simple but I cant get the hang of it. I'm writing a short program where you enter the name, it will compare to each item in the array, then if it is found print what number it is in the array. if it isnt found, then enter a new name

```
Names = ['alice', 'bob', 'carol', 'david']
name = input("Enter Name ").lower()
c = 0
while name != Names[c]:
    c = c + 1
    if c == (len(Names)):
        name = input("Name Not Found \n \nEnter Name ").lower()
        c = 0
if name == Names[c]:
    print ("name found, in position ", c)
```

It Always Comes Up With Name Not Found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you could use `Name.index(name)` and create a recursive function to search for names, like so:

```
Names = ['alice', 'bob', 'carol', 'david']

def findName():
  name = input("Enter Name: ").lower()
  if name in Names:
    print(f'Name at position {Names.index(name)}')
  else: 
    print('Name not found; try again')
    findName()

findName()
```

Or the same code but in a loop:

```
while True:
  name = input("Enter Name: ").lower()
  if name in Names:
    print(f'Name at position {Names.index(name)}')
    break
  else: 
    print('Name not found; try again')
```

Answer (score 2):

name.lower without the () at the end will return the whole lower function and it will mess with the variable

So just replace that with name.lower() and it should work

Answer (score 1):

Use `name = input("Enter Name ").lower()` instead of `name = input("Enter Name ").lower`.
`name = input("Enter Name ").lower` would assign name to the function lower, while `name = input("Enter Name ").lower()` runs the function lower and assigns name its return value